# Spring Boot SAML Authentication Issue with Identity Provider (IdP) on Virtual Machine

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, azure-active-directory, virtual-machine, saml-2.0

I am developing a Spring Boot application with SAML-based Single Sign-On (SSO) authentication, using an Identity Provider (IdP) such as Azure (Microsoft Entra ID). I have configured the IdP with the application and used a proxy to communicate my application with the IdP, which is running at http://localhost:8080. Everything works fine locally.

The problem arises when I deploy the same Spring Boot project on a virtual machine (VM) to run it. The VM address is http://XX.Y.Z.WW:8080/. Since the IdP is configured with the ACS location as http://localhost:8080/login/saml2/sso/adfs

I have attempted to configure the IdP with the VM address (http://XX.Y.Z.WW:8080) but it only accepts addresses with 'localhost'. Is there a workaround or solution to achieve the same behavior on the VM? How can I configure the IdP or Spring Boot application to handle this scenario properly?"

Is there a solution to achieve the same behavior on the VM? How can I configure the IdP or Spring Boot application to handle this scenario properly?"

Comment: The questions you answer tend to be about MS Azure configuration, pricing, infrastructure, and other cloud-related issues, instead of being practical programming problems. StackOverflow is meant to discuss only programming questions. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
for more details. Please post your non-programming question on other platforms such as [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)
, and [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/tags/133/azure)
for immediate help. Thanks!